# Android: What type should I give to AdapterView's parameter?

Tags: android

I have an OnItemClickListener to my ListView like this:

```
OnItemClickListener myClickHandler = new OnItemClickListener(){
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id){
                ...
                }
}
```

However Eclipse is giving me the following warning:

"AdapterView is a raw type. References to generic type AdapterView should be parameterized."

I can't find the right type to put in the parameter, though.

Any clues other than disable generics warnings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use question mark `?` which means refering to any type of object.

```
OnItemClickListener myClickHandler = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Eclipse gave me that suggestion, but I thought it was because it didn't know what I actually should use and I feared it could create a bug down the road. Now I know.